# List of servers & store status in a text file & send a email for ping failed sever

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a VBScript to ping the server and get its output in a text file and send mail for ping failed server only.

When next time script runs, it shoud check the status of the ping in the text file and update the current status on the same place and the mail should be sent for the status change only.

I wrote below script but it only generates the email every time it find status of the server down.

```
Dim strInputPath, strOutputPath, strStatus
Dim objFSO, objTextIn, objTextOut

strInputPath = "E:\test\deep\INPUT.txt" 
strOutputPath = "E:\test\deep\OUTPUT.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextIn = objFSO.OpenTextFile( strInputPath,1 )
Set objTextOut = objFSO.CreateTextFile( strOutputPath )
objTextOut.WriteLine("computer,status")

Do Until objTextIn.AtEndOfStream = True
    strComputer = objTextIn.ReadLine
    If fPingTest( strComputer ) Then
        strStatus = "UP"
    Else
        strStatus = "DOWN"
        Notify_Admins strComputer
    End If
    objTextOut.WriteLine(strComputer & "," & strStatus)
Loop

Function fPingTest( strComputer )
    Dim objShell,objPing
    Dim strPingOut, flag
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Set objPing = objShell.Exec("ping " & strComputer)
    strPingOut = objPing.StdOut.ReadAll
    If InStr(LCase(strPingOut), "reply") Then
        flag = True
    Else
        flag = False
    End If
    fPingTest = flag
End Function

Sub Notify_Admins( strComputer )
    Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    objEmail.From = "pradeep_kumar@gmail.com"
    objEmail.To = "kumarprade@ibm.com"
    objEmail.cc = "kumarprade@ibm.com"
    objEmail.Subject = strComputer & ": is Down"
    objEmail.Textbody = strComputer & " is not pingable on " & Now

    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = _
            "mail.dc.ibm.com" 
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update

    objEmail.Send
End Sub
```

Comment: So in second time, you want to ping only the failed servers and then update the status?

Answer (score 0):

You need the status of the previous run in your input file, otherwise you have no old status to compare against. With the (old) status in the input file you could change your loop to something like this:

```
Do Until objTextIn.AtEndOfStream
    line = Split(objTextIn.ReadLine, ",")
    computer = line(0)
    oldStatus = line(1)
    If fPingTest( computer ) Then
        status = "UP"
    Else
        status = "DOWN"
    End If

    If status <> oldStatus Then
        Notify_Admins computer
    End If

    objTextOut.WriteLine(computer & "," & status)
Loop
```

Replace the input file with the output file at the end of the script:

```
objFSO.DeleteFile strInputPath
objFSO.MoveFile strOutputPath, strInputPath
```